# HTTP error in delete method not working properly

Tags: angular, http, angular7

I have a problem when I am working with HTTP delete method. I have a URL that makes fake API. The address is like this:

```
private URL = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
```

I use get method and store it in the variable `data` and by use of that I generate one table dynamically just like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>userId</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>Tools</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="text" #userId></th>
            <th><input type="text" #id></th>
            <th><input type="text" #title></th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
            <td>{{item.userId}}</td>
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.title}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="updateItem(item)">Update</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteData(item)">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

All my methods work great. But when I want to implement error in my ts file, in the `deleteData` method I have a problem. The code below is `deleteData` in my ts file:

```
deleteData(item) {
       this.service.deletePost(item.id)
       .subscribe(
        response => {
        let index = this.data.indexOf(item);
        this.data.splice(index, 1);
        });    
}
```

I also use service to call my delete service just like that:

```
  deletePost(id){
    return this.http.delete(this.url+'/'+id);
  }
```

My problem:

As you know the second parameter of subscribe method is error and I want to check the 404 not found an error in my table. I have the code just like that:

```
deleteData(item) {
    this.service.deletePost(345)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
        let index = this.data.indexOf(item);
        this.data.splice(index, 1);

      },
       (error:Response) => {
         console.log(error)
         if(error.status == 404)
         {
           alert('404');
         }
         else{
          alert('unexpected is occered!');
          console.log(error);
         }

      });
}
```

In my fake API, I have just 100 items and the last id is 100 when I put invalid id like 345 I should get not found the error and then handle that. But unfortunately it does not happen and the item is deleted. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: what is the response and code  when you use invalid id ?

Comment: it depends on the status code that the server is sending in response, can you pls check the status code of delete response? It might be 200, so that it is not going to error

Comment: yes. i check that in my browser the status code is 200 but when i am using postman application to check status, the status is 200. and it is confusing and response is just empty object like {}.

Comment: actually jsonplaceholder server always return 200 irrespective of object exist or not on server because it's a dummy server for testing purpose only. for detail check answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONPlaceholder is fake backend API server. It won't actually delete anything from their server.

So according to their documentation on [Github](https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#how-to) it will always return the `200` as the response if you trying to delete something from the server.

**Here is Screenshot**

[image]

Hope this will help!

Comment: you right but if you delete sth at the same time it deletes. there is tutorial that use that case and you can see the result. but my code is not running correct.

Comment: Okay, but then I have one question how to check invalid delete requests?

Comment: @amir-mehrizi You are right but I'm unable to verify this as that tutorial was 2 years old. I can't say for sure if any bug was introduced later as postman also receives status: 200 and delete do not return a response as per my knowledge.